# Unknown animation name: decelerateInterpolator

Tags: android, android-animation

```
Android Studio 1.5
Device Samsung 4.4.2
```

I am trying to animate items loaded from a ArrayList into a recyclerview. I when the dropdown arrow is clicked the items should animate (decelerate) when expanded and should animate when collapsed. However, currently the list items just appears.

Code that calls the setAnimation

```
 @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(ChatChildViewHolder childViewHolder, int position, Object childListItem) {
        ChatChildTitles chatChildTitles = (ChatChildTitles)childListItem;
        childViewHolder.tvChildTitle.setText(chatChildTitles.getTitle());

        setAnimation(childViewHolder.cvChildRooms, position);
    }
```

Code for setting the animation

```
  private void setAnimation(CardView viewToAnimate, int position) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, android.R.anim.fade_in);
        animation.setInterpolator(mContext, android.R.anim.decelerate_interpolator);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
    }
```

Here is a couple of screenshots:

In the collapsed state

[image]

After the arrow has been clicked expland the list
[image]

This is my layout I am using that represents the rows that will be displayed in the recyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cvChildRooms"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card:cardBackgroundColor="@color/child_header_lighter_grey"
    card:contentPadding="4dp"
    card:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:src="@drawable/photorace"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvChildTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:text="Coffee Latte Room"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I have a function that should start the animation.

```
private void setAnimation(CardView viewToAnimate, int position) {
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, android.R.anim.decelerate_interpolator);
    viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

I have tested using the following that works ok with `slide_in_left`. However, I don't want them to slide in from the left

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Can you explain exactly what kind of animation do you want for your items? As Mattia Maestrini already pointed out, using an interpolator as animation makes no sense..

Comment: I might have something for u, but can only give you an answer tomorrow. Can u please tell me if your question is twofolded? You are asking for help with 1. When the top recyclerview is loaded initially loaded, the item must be animate and 2. When u click the dropdown, the item that appears must be animated when the recyclerview is expanding and collapsing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use a *decelerate interpolator* **you need to set it AS an interpolator, not as the animator**:

```
private void setAnimation(CardView viewToAnimate, int position) {
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, android.R.anim.fade_in); //change this with your desidered (or custom) animation
    animation.setInterpolator(mContext, android.R.anim.decelerate_interpolator);
    viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

You said that you are using [com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:2.0.3](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view).

**From the official docs of the library, it's clearly state how to create expand/collapse animations**:

> You can also create your own animations for expansion by overriding
>   `ParentViewHolder#onExpansionToggled(boolean)`, which will be called for
>   you when the itemView is expanded or collapsed.

I suggest you to take a look at the [official example](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view/tree/master/app) of the library.

Comment: I tried your snippet but it didn't work for me. I have updated my question with some screenshots. Basically, I want to animate the list when the recyclerview is expanded and collapsed.

Comment: @ant2009 Can you give some more info? E.g post the code that you are using to invoke your `setAnimation()` method

Comment: I have updated my questions with the required code snippets. For the recyclerview, I am using the com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:2.0.3

Comment: @ant2009 I've just updated my answer accordingly to the information yuo've provided

Answer (score 7):

You can't use `decelerate_interpolator` because it's not an animation, it is an interpolator:

> An interpolator defines the rate of change of an animation. This
>   allows the basic animation effects (alpha, scale, translate, rotate)
>   to be accelerated, decelerated, repeated, etc.
>
> Reference:
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html

As you can see the XML that describing them are completely different:

[Source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/core/res/res/anim/decelerate_interpolator.xml) of `decelerate_interpolator.xml`:

```
<decelerateInterpolator />
```

[Source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/core/res/res/anim/slide_in_left.xml) of `slide_in_left.xml`:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 2):

To animate the list as they expand and collapse, consider using an ItemAnimator from android.

You will need to set up a custom itemAnimator, something similar to the one in the link below:

https://gist.github.com/ademar111190/dc988c8d899dae0193f7

Set the itemAnimator in the method runPendingAnimations to your decelerate interpolator.

```
@Override
    public void runPendingAnimations() {
        if (!mViewHolders.isEmpty()) {
            int animationDuration = 300;
            AnimatorSet animator;
            View target;
            for (final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder : mViewHolders) {
                target = viewHolder.itemView;
                target.setPivotX(target.getMeasuredWidth() / 2);
                target.setPivotY(target.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);

                animator = new AnimatorSet();

                animator.playTogether(
                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "translationX", -target.getMeasuredWidth(), 0.0f),
                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "alpha", target.getAlpha(), 1.0f)
                );

                animator.setTarget(target);
                animator.setDuration(animationDuration);
                animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                animator.setStartDelay((animationDuration * viewHolder.getPosition()) / 10);
                animator.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mViewHolders.remove(viewHolder);
                    }
                });
                animator.start();
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you will need to set the itemAnimator to the recycler view.

recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new MyItemAnimator());

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code for do that.

```
private void hideViews() {
  recyclerView.animate().translationY(-recyclerView.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2));

  FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mFabButton.getLayoutParams();
  int fabBottomMargin = lp.bottomMargin;
  mFabButton.animate().translationY(mFabButton.getHeight()+fabBottomMargin).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
}

private void showViews() {
  recyclerView.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));
  mFabButton.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
}
```

You can call this method **onClick** of your Button.

Hope it will help you.